# Disable "Share Mac Analytics" with defaults command?

Tags: privacy

I'm trying to disable all analytics feature with the `defaults` command:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score -2):

```bsh
sudo defaults write /Library/Application\ Support/CrashReporter/DiagnosticMessagesHistory.plist AutoSubmit -int 0
```